# PHP Function default variable value to DateTime+24h

Tags: php, datetime, increment

I need to declare a function that takes a string of format MySQL DateTime or by default would use the current DateTime + 24 hours

Something like :

```
function myFunction($next_date = new DateTime()->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')) {
    echo "Next date : " . $next_date;
}
```

I can't find a way that works, thank you.

Comment: please consider my late answer as the accepted answer.  In my opinion using Nishanth's DateTime object method is overkill when my one-liner with larger php version support does the same job with less coding.  This is not about point grubbing, it is about identifying the best answer for future SO readers.  (Nishanth, sorry to do this again to you, it is purely coincidence -- I'm not trolling your answers; datetime is one of my fav tags.  As far as I can tell, your method is also correct.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just that you have a syntax error in your code:

Before using any instance of a class you should be assiging it to a variable

So, before doing: `new DateTime()->` you should be doing `$dateTime = new DateTime()` and then `$dateTime->`

So, try modifying your code to this:

```
function myFunction($next_date = null) {
    if(!$next_date) {
        $dateTime = new DateTime();
        $next_date = $dateTime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    echo "Next date : " . $next_date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of this way around, I was trying to fit all in the function declaration...

Comment: @Fredovsky Np! happy coding

Comment: A word of caution to all readers regarding `DateTime()` and timezone declarations: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#104111

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who can't or doesn't want to use the [DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) construct because of their php version or personal preference (like they really love one-liners), you can use this instead:

```
$next_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Personally, I don't see the need to create and manipulate an object for such a simple task.

Comment: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+1 day"));` would suffice

Comment: @billynoah Oh, yes, quite right, when I was doing some tests I was hard coding in a date that caused trouble with bunkerboy's answer given a specific timezone.  I'll update my answer, thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @mickmackusa sorry but now vote is locked, please edit something then i ll remove my downvote